# Change submenu's position

Tags: joomla, submenu

I'd like to change my sub-menu from horizontal to vertical, please let me know how this is possible...

My li is:

```
position: relative;
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
```

and ul is:

```
position: absolute;
top: 95%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: left;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 2px 0 0;
list-style: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
display: table-cell;
```

to

```
display: block
```

This should do it. Make sure you clear your Joomla and browser cache once you do this.